# IntelliJ maven project import issues

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ. I wanted to import existing Maven project.

I have done:

`File->Import Project...->[selected pom.xml]->Finish...`

Project gets imported, I can see all the files. In bottom left corner it says `Resolving dependencies of [project name]`. After some time it is finished. Problem is, I have no Maven Libraries in my project.

More interesting, IntelliJ created all folders structures for libraries in maven repository (`.m/repository/`), but they are all EMPTY.
I started investigating, and it looks like there is a problem with my pom.xml, but I have no idea why.
For example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

is marked as error: `Dependency "org.springframework:spring:core:3.2.0.RELEASE" not found.`

It is the same for all my other dependencies. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

I checked Maven repositories settings, and *local* repository is set properly. But there might be a problem with *Remote* repository. When I click on it and then click "Update", there is an error. 
URL is `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`

Comment: make sure under Setting->maven->repositories local repository is specified

Comment: it is. As I wrote, it even creates libraries folders structure there, like `org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.0.RELEASE`, but it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need tell maven where to get the repositories from.
You need to specify the maven remote (or local) repository that the libraries are. 
in this case I guess you need to add something like this:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central maven repo</id>
            <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: Looks like my problem was wrong settings.xml file. It came out that for a project I am working on we have dedicated repository. Thanks, as your answer is correct in fact :)